# Drupal and wordpress on the same site

Tags: wordpress, drupal, .htaccess

I have a drupal installation in the root directly of my domain with clean urls enabled. 
I also have a sub directory with wordpress installed. /blog/ 
I also have a sub directory with php scripts in it /utilities/

When I type in "http://www.domain.com/blog/a-post/" I get a 404 error from Drupal telling me that the page does not exist. same goes with "http://www.domain.com/utilities/pig/"

I know this has something to do with the ".htaccess" file. That was created when I turned on "clean urls" in Drupal.

I'm looking for information on how to set up the .htaccess file or a code snippet that i could use to tell Drupal to ignore these two directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/utilities/.*$
```

below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
```

You should be fine.